# XY to Line tool doesn't run

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, distance

I am trying to run the tool on this simple [table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xc5snq0lkx5xmew/test.xls?dl=0) using Point X, Point Y, Xt0 and Yt0 fields for calculating distances. But immediately as the tool runs, it stops with an error "a*n expected field was not found or could not be retrieved properly*". This error is shown for every single feature in the results window. I have tried exporting to a new table, removing features with null XY coordinates, exporting to a geodatabase, restarting ArcMap...everything possible. Even google doesn't give me a solution.

What is wrong with my table?

Comment: Guess: are you specifying the output spatial reference, and if you are, is it the same as the table's coordinates?

Comment: Yes I am specifiying a very specific spatial reference which is the same as the coordinates in the table.

Comment: I don't know what CRS your points are in but the XY to Line tool worked fine for me when I generated the geometry using my local CRS.

Comment: can you show a sample of your data?  it's hard to guess what's wrong with it without seeing it.

Comment: @jbalk the data table is attached in the link in the question

Comment: @GBG you mean it worked on my table? The CRS I am using is this 'DHDN_3_Degree_Gauss_Zone_2'. The thing is the tool worked for me with this same CRS before for another table. There is something wrong with this table.

Comment: @Salman-Well, I got the XY to Line tool to draw a bunch of lines that point to the area around Essen Germany using DHDN_3_Degree_Gauss_Zone_2.  I don't know how to insert an image of the output here to show you....

Comment: thanks.  Have you tried saving the table as a csv before processing?  I find this helps remove errors in excel docs.  Alternatively, select all your data in the table and clear the formatting before processing.  Sometimes formatting causes errors with excel docs in arc.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters listed below produce the lines shown in the second picture using your table.  No error message was returned by ArcGIS.  I am using 10.5.1, maybe you should try installing the latest service pack from ESRI for your version of ArcGIS.

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks this definitely seems to be a solution and I will make sure I update to the latest version as soon as possible. But I am not in a position to update at the moment before I complete my analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I checked if the tool was working if I used Point_X,  Point_Y with another random set of coordinates and it worked! So I assumed the problem is with xt0 and yt0 fields. So I first copied those two fields to an excel table, deleted them from the attribute table and then joined them back using the excel table. Now the tool somehow worked. It looks like one of those weird solutions that somehow work sometimes in ArcGIS :)